# window.opener=null for new windows like popups, submit, form, with target=blank

Tags: javascript, forms, hyperlink, window.opener, cross-origin-opener-policy

I had a Problem, but in this case I found some solutions here and on other websites I want to share with you.

Problem:
window.opener functions of child pages were not working anymore since some security updates of the modern browsers about 2020 / 2021.

If you open a new link from your site via target="_blank" then in most cases the window.opener functions will not work anymore.

Solutions: see Answer below.
I hope I could help other people with this solution.

I have searched many hours to solve these problems. I have even tried to allow the old behaviour via .htaccess but without success.
If anybody has a working solution via .htacces please add a post or an answer.

Comment: It's good if you share your knowledge in the form of self-answered question, but if you do so, your question should contain your question only and you should move the answer part into an answer in order to comply to the format of stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hello Lajos. This was my first posting. Thank you for your information. I have edited the main posting and added solution as an answer. Hope this is right now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit XXL-Webdesign. Now the question is nicely separated from the answer. Let's hope this knowledge-share will help lots of people. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple href links you just have to add rel="opener" to get it working again.

```
<a href="https://myPage.com/childpage.php" target="_blank" rel="opener">Link to child page</a>
```

For some JavaScripts (one sample here) you can add setAttributs to your scripts

```
(...)
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "myChildPage.php");
// form.setAttribute("target","_blank");        // old
form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");      // new: setting form target to a window named 'formresult'
form.setAttribute("rel","opener");          // need to add because of security changes of newer browsers
(...)
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

For some Buttons with input type="submit" this is not as easy as the solutions before... The rel="opener" does not work within the button if you use formaction, formtarget (...)

Not working (rel="opener" in INPUT tag):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
(...)
<input type="submit" value="My Submit Button" formaction="childpage.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_blank" rel="opener">
</form>
```

Working (rel="opener" in FORM tag)

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" rel="opener">
(...)
<input type="submit" value="My Submit Button" formaction="childpage.php" formmethod="post" formtarget="_blank" rel="opener">
</form>
```